# Using a foreach array outside a class inside a class?

Tags: php

I hope the title makes sense, I am learning to use PHP classes and I am understanding pretty well, I am trying to go beyond the tutorials I have read/watched and use an array to return the values.

I am purely just experimenting and curious to know why what I am doing is wrong (I didnt add my foreach attempts, hoping someone can point out where to run a foreach on the `getTheGameType()` method) and the proper way to go about it.

```
//Just a manual array containing key/value pairs of games with their genres 
$array = array(
        "Grand Theft Auto" => "Action",
        "NBA 2k14" => "Sports",
        "COD" => "Shooting",
);

//My object
class videoGames {


    public $title;
    public $genere;

    public function setTheGameType($title,$genere) {

        $this->title = $title;
        $this->genere = $genere;
    }

    public function getTheGameType() {

            return 'The game genre for '.$this->title.' is:' . $this->genere;

    }

}

//New instance of `videoGames` class
$list = new videoGames();

//Here I set the game title with its genere
foreach ($array as $title => $genere) {
    $list-> setTheGameType($title,$genere);
}

//Echo the value passed into getTheGameType() function
    echo $list->getTheGameType();
```

The above returns The game genre for COD is:Shooting which gets the last value of the array..

How do I return all key/value pairs essentially looping the `getTheGameType()` method?

**Edit:** *I got it working by adding  `echo $list->getTheGameType();` into the foreach loop.*

Question to the method? Is this bad practice?

```
   foreach ($array as $title => $genere) {
    $list-> setTheGameType($title,$genere);
    echo $list->getTheGameType();
}
```

Comment: Put `echo` statement inside `foreach`, after `setTheGameType` statement.

Comment: Oh dang, that was it... I ran a foreach separately on the `echo $list->getTheGameType();` which caused it to loop the last value three times.. this worked great :)

Comment: Your code doesn't seem right though, you should be creating an array of instances of the class. What you're doing now is basically re-assign the properties of the same class a bunch of times. That's not how OOP works...

Comment: Okay, was hoping to get tips like this.. Again I am learning to use classes watched a few tutorials and tried to write something on my own... Looks like the answers below help :)

Comment: Please keep in mind the comment by niloct will echo the names as it appears in the array but it is not the answer to your problem. That echo will still just overwrite the title of the single game instance you created.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry the answers below are good practice, but first you may want to understand why your code didn't work. After you get that you may refactor your code and improve it.

Comment: @Niloct I would also argue that learning how to use a feature like OOP correctly in the first place (as shown in my example), may save him from trying to debug code that never really made sense.  In other words, it's easier to debug good code :-)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart if he doesn't see why the code he posted doesn't work, perhaps he's not ready to understand OOP refactoring.

Comment: One of the "problems" with `php` is how loose of a language it is. Using inconsistent naming and syntax establishes poor practices that will hurt you both when using `php` and when trying to learn other languages. With that in mind, I would suggest (if you haven't already done so), finding a series of respected conventions and sticking to them. Here is an example: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.bestpractices.php

Comment: My above comment, btw, was in anticipation of the answers you have received, including conventions like `class VideoGame` as opposed to `class video_game_collection` as opposed to `class videoGames`. These are all fine (`class videoGames` is a bit sketchy), but whichever you choose you should stick to, and ensure all your code sticks to it. It will avoid a lot of confusion down the road.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not really using classes correctly in this example. An object should model, well, an object:

```
class VideoGame {          // Singular title (not gameS)

    private $title;        // Make these private - information hiding
    private $genre;        // spell this correctly!  :-)

    // Use a constructor to initialize fields in the class!
    public function __construct($title,$genre) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->genre = $genre;
    }

    // Here are "getters" for the two fields.
    // Note that I have not provided "setters" - so these fields will
    // always have their initial value (as set in the constructor).
    // Types like this (with no setters) are often called "immutable".
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getGenre() {
        return $this->genre;
    }

    public function getDescriptiveString() {
        return $this->title . ' is a ' . $this->genre . ' game.\n';
    }

}
```

Creating these:

```
// This array has three instances of the VideoGame object.
// Often, this would actually be the result of a database query.
$game_array = array(
    new VideoGame("Grand Theft Auto", "Action"),
    new VideoGame("NBA 2k14", "Sports"),
    new VideoGame("COD", "Shooting")
);
```

Iterating over them:

```
// We get the descriptive string from each game and print it.
foreach ($game_array as $game) {
    echo $game->getDescriptiveString();
}
```

See also:

- [ooPHP - How do I create an array of objects from an associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913712/oophp-how-do-i-create-an-array-of-objects-from-an-associative-array)

Comment: So when working with an object you wouldnt use a standard array?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with it. Note that I have created an array of objects (with no keys, only values).  You are using an associative array in your example, where you specify keys and values.

Comment: Okay I see you're using the constructor, this is common I see in actual plugins and applications, but the two tutorials I watched didnt cover that, thanks for that though it helps as I will need to learn the constructor... so you are saying though I can use an associative array, because I know its manual but if I wanted to interact with a database, wouldnt it most likely be in associtive array form, that is of course if I make it that way..

Comment: I mean, you could have an `array( "COD" => new VideoGame("COD", "Shooting"), ... )` but since the title is already part of the object, there's no point in having the title as the key.

Comment: Okay, so let me note the difference between the two array types.. array of objects and associative arrays, didnt know there was different array types honestly I am so used to seeing the associative. So thanks for that, now I am going to analyze your code a little more to get my head to wrap around it more.. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No, it is not "array of objects" vs. "associative arrays". Arrays (in php) are just lists of things, and those things can be whatever you want. Those things take the form of a unique key in the list, and a value. That is what you are doing when you say `"Grand Theft Auto" => "Action"`- in that case, `"Grand Theft Auto"` is the key, and `"Action"` is the value. In the example @JonathonReinhart gave, he did not specify a key, so php just counts up from 0 and uses numbers as the keys. The values he used happened to be objects. Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2):

You're instantiating a single instance of the class and rewriting the type. I assume you want each game to have its own instance of the class:

```
$games = array();

//Here I set the game title with its genere
foreach ($array as $title => $genere) {
    //New instance of `videoGames` class
    $list = new videoGames();
    $list->setTheGameType($title,$genere);
    $games[] = $list;
}

foreach($games AS $game)
{
    echo $game->getTheGameType();
}
```

However, see jonathon's answer about the architecture of a class. This answer is just to show why you are getting the results you have now.

Answer (score 2):

Well right now, your `videoGames` class is really not properly named.  Currently it can store only one video game.  When you are running a loop, you are just resetting the class properties for title and genre on the object.

If you really want to work in OOP, you probably need two classes, one for the video game, and one to represent a collection of video games.  So let's just assume you keep you current class as is but rename it `video_game` (singular).

Then you might want to add a class to store the video games like this:

```
class video_game_collection {
    protected $collection = array();

    // allow construction of collection by passing array of video_games (though not required)
    public __construct($game_array = null) {
        // validate all array elements are proper objects if the array is set
        if(is_array($game_array)) {
            foreach ($array as $game) {
                if ($game instanceof video_game === false) {
                    throw new Exception('You sent a date array element.');
                } else {
                    $this->collection[] = $game;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public add_video_game($game) {
        if ($game instanceof video_game === false) {
            throw new Exception ('This is not a game.');
        }
        $this->collection[] = $game;
    }

    public get_collection() {
        return $this->collection;
    }
}
```

You probably should not have logic like that echoes messaging inside you class (limit the class to a single purpose - to represent the data object).  So I would suggest you just return the game type in your getGameType method, rather than have it actually echo text.  Leave the messaging to something outside the class.

Putting it together, yo could do something like

```
$collection = new video_game_collection();

//Just a manual array containing key/value pairs of games with their genres 
$array = array(
        "Grand Theft Auto" => "Action",
        "NBA 2k14" => "Sports",
        "COD" => "Shooting",
);

foreach($array as $game => $genre) {
    $game = new videoGame();
    $game->setTheGameType($game, $genre);
    $collection->add_video_game($game);
}
```

Now you have a collection you could do things against, like return all titles, or if yo build added functionality, sort by title, return movies of a specific genre, return all genres, etc.

Comment: This just goes to show that you can create objects/arrays etc etc in multiple ways, every programmer has their preference and logic. Thanks for this I am going over it now.

Comment: Yes.  Once you work more with OOP you will realize that the class.  I think the answer from @JohnathonReinhart gives you a good example of how to change your video game class.  I was intending to show you an object oriented way of working with collections of objects (though very basic).  You could easily add logic to update an array that stores genres and all objects of that genre, or functionality to sort by title or some other property of the video game that you might decide to add.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will definitely use this as a resource I thought your answer and @JohnathonReinhart were fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over an array, and successfully storing a title and genre in the object on each iteration of the loop.  However, you are also overwriting the values stored in the object each time.  When you run `$list->getTheGameType();`, you are seeing the last value you put in, because it overwrote the previous values.

If you want your object to store information about several games, modify it to store the data in a nested array (or even a new class of object, representing a single game).  If your class is designed to contain a single game, then you will want to make an array of videoGames objects, storing information about one game in each object.  It's all about how you want to model the data.

Comment: Thanks this is pretty clear, again I am just learning classes and objects so some of this logic will make much more sense when I get real hands on experience... this will definitely fully ring a bell soon enough.. thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  Objects are a lot to wrap your head around, but I can see you're learning.  Keep hunting up more tutorials.  There are many excellent resources you can find out there.  Codecademy has a PHP section now, check it out:  http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-StaFQ/0/1?curriculum_id=5124ef4c78d510dd89003eb8